# Extract a Particular Information from a HTML Code of a webpage?

Tags: r, html-parsing, dplyr, rcurl, stringr

I have a webpage "http://www.jabong.com/playdate-Off-White-Casual-Top-1342500.html?pos=1" and I am able to get the HTML code of it...but I need to extract particular information...from the above page I would need the below information:

**Type : Casual Tops, Fabric : Cotton, Sleeves : Half Sleeves, Neck : Round Neck, Fit : Regular, Wash Care : Hand Wash, Use Mild Detergents, Remove Belts / Broaches Before Wash, Color : Off White, Fabric Details : 95/5 Cotton Lycra, Style : Graphic, SKU : PL527KA99JYQINDFAS**

Comment: You need a web scraping package, such as [rvest](https://github.com/hadley/rvest).

Comment: @alistaire : You didnot get the question right..I am able get the complete HTML Code...I need extract particular information only...so I guess Stringr package will help..but I need a code that can extract that particular info..thanks

Comment: `rvest` can scrape, yes, but most of scraping is parsing, which is what you need to do. Don't parse HTML with regex; it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an HTML scraper/parser such as [`rvest`](https://github.com/hadley/rvest):

```
library(rvest)

url <- 'http://www.jabong.com/playdate-Off-White-Casual-Top-1342500.html?pos=1'

# get HTML, select list node with the information
page <- url %>% read_html() %>% html_node('.prod-main-wrapper') 

# select the nodes within the list of each type, and get the text inside
variable <- page %>% html_nodes('label') %>% html_text()
value <- page %>% html_nodes('span') %>% html_text()

# put the text in a nice data.frame
data.frame(variable, value)
#          variable                                                               value
# 1            Type                                                         Casual Tops
# 2          Fabric                                                              Cotton
# 3         Sleeves                                                        Half Sleeves
# 4            Neck                                                          Round neck
# 5             Fit                                                             Regular
# 6       Wash Care Hand Wash, Use Mild Detergents, Remove Belts / Broaches Before Wash
# 7           Color                                                           Off White
# 8  Fabric Details                                                   95/5 Cotton Lycra
# 9           Style                                                             Graphic
# 10            SKU                                                  PL527KA99JYQINDFAS
# 11  Authorization          Playdate authorized online sales partner. View Certificate
```